# connect copper without soldering

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, copper, copper-tubing, soldering

I need to connect bow copper as on the picture with a copper pipe, and I'd like to avoid soldering. Is there a special tool for this?

[image: bow copper]

Comment: It's not really clear what you're hoping to hear ... Those fittings are intended to be soldered and the 'special tool' is either a torch or large soldering iron.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I've thought there might be some sort of clamp tool, instead of soldering, which could be dangerous for beginner in the first place.

Comment: There are solderless methods of connecting copper (ex. sharkbite). This kind of question is moving a little into the product recommendation world, however...

Comment: What is your application?  If you need a water-tight connection for plumbing purposes, those are designed to be soldered.  If it is for a hobby project where a sealed connection isn't needed, other methods might be good enough.  If it is a plumbing application, is there an issue with soldering?

Comment: [Sharkbite](http://www.sharkbite.com/) or solder... your choice.

Comment: Soldering is easy, even for a beginner. YouTube.

Comment: You avoid soldering by using press-on connectors (Sharkbite) to adapt to pex  tubing (crimp connectors). You don't screw around with copper. Like Paul said, sweating joints is easy and is no more dangerous than operating a birthday cake.

Comment: A good solder connection is an art and takes lots of practice.  Just ask people that had novice plumbers  with little experiance, solder their copper only to find that shortly after that the joints leaked or worse and they had a mess to clean up. Also, I do not like "sharkbite" fittings because they reduce the flow due the restriction in the fitting. No real professional would ever use them.  just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a system for connecting copper tubing and copper fittings that does not use solder. Just google "Propress" for an example. Some places rent the tool or you can purchase one. Before I retired the company I worked for used this tool for a lot of 
 copper fittings from 1/2" thru 4". It works very well, is quick and does a lasting job.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid soldering I would use either a compression elbow or a push-fit elbow. But it depends on what the pipe is carrying (water or gas).

[image: Compression Elbow]
[image: Push fit elbow]

Useful tools include pipe-cutters and appropriate sized spanners/wrenches.

Comment: Agreed, for a newb who needs to make a quick repair, a compression fitting or a proprietary push-fit solution (like Sharkbite) is probably the best recommendation.  Another advantage of these approaches is that the repair can be made even if the pipe is dripping, which is possible but much harder to do with soldering, requiring special techniques or tools.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're planning on using the pipes for, you could use an epoxy that was designed for metal to metal bonds.

I wouldn't use epoxy for a constant pressure in-wall application, but I did use it to extend a short nipple for a tub spout on an acrylic tub. I wrapped it in a heating pad to post cure for extra insurance.